# Updating a Table Based on a Timestamp Value in the Table

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database using phpmyadmin.
I have a table consisting ID (integer), Status (integer), and Date (timestamp).

For example :

```
-------------------------------------------
  ID   |    Status   |        Date        
-------------------------------------------
   1   |      1      | 2019-05-10 00:00:00
   2   |      1      | 2019-05-11 00:00:00
-------------------------------------------
```

I want to change the Status value from 1 into 2 when the SYSDATE is reaching the Date record. How can I do that ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Create an [event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) on your database and run UPDATE query.

*or*

2. Create a [CRON job](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428) to run specific PHP file on your server where will be your UPDATE query.

*And set them to run e.g. for every day.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this option:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET Status = 2
WHERE CURDATE() >= Date AND Status = 1;
```

This assumes that your `Date` column in fact stores just dates.  If it stores timestamps, and you only want to flag when the current timestamp exceeds the `Date` column, then use `SYSDATE()` instead:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET Status = 2
WHERE SYSDATE() >= Date AND Status = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
update  my_table  
set statys = 2 
where 
WHERE CURDATE() >= FROM_UNIXTIME(Date) 
AND Status = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Update tablename SET Status = 2 Where CURDATE() >= Date AND Status = 1;
```

OR

```
Update tablename SET Status = 2 Where Date >= NOW()  AND Status = 1;
```